# Characters are still being captured and highlighted despite using do not capture command

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm using Regex in R and I am trying to capture a specific measurement of cardiac wall thickness that has 1-2 digits and 0-2 decimals as in:

```
"maximum thickness of lv wall= 1.5"
```

yet I want to exclude instances where `(after|myectomy|resection)` is somewhere after the word `"thickness"`

So I wrote the following regex code:

```
pattern <- "(?i)(?<=thickness)(?!(\\s{0,10}[[:alpha:]]{1,100}){0,8}\\s{0,10}(after|myectomy|resection))(?:(?:\\s{0,10}[[:alpha:]]{0,100}){0,8}\\s{0,10}[:=\\(]?)\\d{1,3}\\.?\\d{0,3}"
```

you can test it against this sample dataframe (every measurement in this example should match, except the last one):

```
df <- tibble(
  test = c("maximum size of thickness in base to mid of anteroseptal wall(1.7cm)",
           "(anterolateral and inferoseptal wall thickness:1.6cm)",
           "hypertrophy in apical segments maximom thickness=1.6cm with sparing of posterior wall",
           "septal thickness=1cm",
           "LV apical segments with maximal thickness 1.7 cm and dynamic",
           "septal thickness after myectomy=1cm")
)
```

this regex code works for Matching what I want; the problem is that here I want to capture the measurements only, yet the sections behind the measurement are also getting captured although I have stated otherwise through none-capturing groups `?:` .

Check this image out that is a result of `stringr::str_view(df$test, pattern)`:

[image]

Comment: Non-capturing group patterns still consume text, so it always lands in the output.

Comment: so how can I prevent that?

Comment: I would be grateful if you could introduce another pattern that gets it right. I have been wrestling with it for the past 5 hours with no luck

Comment: You need to clarify: do you want to fail the match when one of the 3 words appears *between* `thickness` and the number? Or anywhere after `thickness`, even if it is after the number?

Comment: The former, I want the match to fail when any of `(after|myectomy|resection)` words appears between thickness and the number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
pattern <- "(?i)(?<=\\bthickness(?:\\s{1,10}(?!(?:after|myectomy|resection)\\b)[a-zA-Z]{1,100}){0,8}\\s{0,10}[:=(]?)\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3})?"
str_view(df$test, pattern)
```

Output:

[image]

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9aJGj0/1/) (JavaScript engine in modern browsers supports unlimited length lookbehind).

*Details*:

- `(?<=` - start of the positive lookbehind that requires the following sequence of patterns to match immediately to the left of the current location:

  - `\bthickness` - whole word `thickness`
  - `(?:\s{1,10}(?!(?:after|myectomy|resection)\b)[a-zA-Z]{1,100}){0,8}` - zero to eight occurrences of

    - `\s{1,10}` - one to ten whitespaces
    - `(?!(?:after|myectomy|resection)\b)` - no `after`, `mectomy` and `resection` words are allowed immediately to the right of the current location
    - `[a-zA-Z]{1,100}` - 1 to 100 ASCII letters
  - `\s{0,10}` - zero to ten whitespaces
  - `[:=(]?` - an optional `:`, `=` or `(` char
- `)` - end of the positive lookbehind
- `\d{1,3}` - one to three digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,3})?` - an optional sequence of a `.` and then one to three digits.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, as always the best and most concise answer. I've learnt a lot from you. I'll make sure to practice with the demo. thanks again

Comment: excuse me for asking too many questions, but the weird thing is that the pattern you so kindly wrote, works pretty fine in the Regex Demo, and also seems to have worked fine in your R output results.[but my R doesn't return the same result](https://imgur.com/a/fEjunja)
any idea what could have gone wrong?
P.S: it happens when I add the second look around.

Comment: @KasraMehdizadeh You must have used a different code then. Please also update your packages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you break it down to smaller steps.

```
tt <- regmatches(s, regexpr("(?i)thickness.*?\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{1,3})?", s, perl = TRUE))
is.na(tt) <- grep("after|myectomy|resection", tt)
sub("[^0-9]*", "", tt)
#[1] "1.7" "1.6" "1.6" "1"   "1.7" NA
```

Data:

```
s <- c("maximum size of thickness in base to mid of anteroseptal wall(1.7cm)",
       "(anterolateral and inferoseptal wall thickness:1.6cm)",
       "hypertrophy in apical segments maximom thickness=1.6cm with sparing of posterior wall",
       "septal thickness=1cm",
       "LV apical segments with maximal thickness 1.7 cm and dynamic",
       "septal thickness after myectomy=1cm")
```